# What is correct syntax to verify a certificate in the certificate store using certutil.exe?

Tags: windows, certificate

I have a client certificate in certstore. I try this:

```
certutil.exe -verify CertCommonName
```

but in get this error when I ping certutil.exe -ping it connect to pc.

```
DecodeFile returned The system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2)       

LoadCert(Cert) returned The system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2) 

CertUtil: -verify command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2) CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CertCommonName you need to give the filepath path to a certificate file i.e. certutil -verify examplecertificate.cer rather than certutil.exe -verify CertCommonName. The way you have its looking for a file called CertCommonname and cant find it.

Comment: Additional documentation on this can be found in the CertUtil documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil#BKMK_verify). As the syntax is `CertUtil [Options] -verify CertFile [CACertFile [CrossedCACertFile]]`, the certificate name should indeed be replaced by the filename (or path) of the certificate as answered above.